# Angular(5) Firebase Deployment Issue

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am attempting to deploy an Angular5/Firebase application to Firebase. All steps during the Firebase-CLI deployment process seem fine. The main page works on the deployed site. (It is our Welcome Controller). However, none of the links work. When I try to navigate to a sub-page on the site, the browser shows this.

[image: scrnsht]

During the CLI deployment process. I answered this

"What do you want to use as your public directory?"

With

"dist"

Here is my firebase.json

```
{
  "database": {
    "rules": "database.rules.json"
  },
  "firestore": {
    "rules": "firestore.rules",
    "indexes": "firestore.indexes.json"
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": "dist",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ]
  },
  "storage": {
    "rules": "storage.rules"
  },
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint",
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run build"
    ]
  }
}
```

Here is the link

https://west-oaks-fe502.firebaseapp.com/

Comment: Have you build before deployement ?

Comment: What's in your dist directory? The Angular CLI will default to `dist/project_name` in which case that's what you should put in your firebase.json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During the Firebase-CLI deployment process, this question

"Configure as single page app?"

Should be

"yes"